# No payment module is displayed First Data Payeezy

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment

I installed this module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/first-data-payeezy-with-transarmor.html

I have correctly configured the field, but this method of payment is the only one to use is not displayed when I pay. There is no error and the system.log shows nothing. This also installed an SSL.

Comment: Did you install your theme to all file